# How can I pass "Select" into a Generic query using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a generic method using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core. The method looks like this:

```
     protected virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryableDymanic<TEntity>(
        string filter = null,
        string orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = null,
        int? skip = null,
        int? take = null,
        params object[] parameters)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        includeProperties = includeProperties ?? string.Empty;
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = context.Set<TEntity>();

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter,parameters);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            query = query.OrderBy(orderBy);
        }

        if (skip.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Skip(skip.Value);
        }

        if (take.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Take(take.Value);
        }

        return query;
    }
```

I want to add a `string SelectedColumns` parameter so I can also specify which columns are returned. Null would return all columns and supplying a comma delimited string would return only the specified columns. So my method it might look something like this:

```
        if (SelectedColumns != null)
        {
            query = query.Select($"new({SelectedColumns})");
        }
```

While something like `.Select("new(CompanyName as Name, Phone)")` perfectly legal syntax for a plain old dynamic linq query, in this scenario it throws a conversion error:

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<TEntity>'
```

So even though I should be able to use `.Select()` to specify what columns to return there doesn't seem to be a way to do it with `TEntity`. Is this simply not possible? I tried going the DTO route and creating an object with fewer properties, but that created even more issues.

Anyone know how I can accomplish this? I've scoured the web and there seem to be some published solutions for doing this with T but not TEntity.

Comment: `query` is not dynamic linq query coz it holds information about the type of the entity `TEntity`. When you use dynamic select the result becomes dynamic which can't be simply casted to typed query. Select should be creating news instances of `TEntity` while selecting only a few properties of it.

Comment: So basically it can't be done. That's kinda what I thought would be the answer.

Comment: What you said was legal syntax would not be legal at runtime for the same reason - did you try it? The return type from a select is a new anonymous type, which isn't the same type as `TEntity`. You would need some type of dynamic object to handle this.

Comment: I ended up just using a DTO to limit the properties returned. The dynamics stuff would just get too messy. Not crazy about having to use a bunch of DTOs to limit the data coming back from the server but it is the standard way to handle it for now. Thanks for the info.